# How to register for an event that reminds app on specified time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have requirement to initiate sync on every night at 1 AM or every 2 weeks. How will I achieve this in iOS? Is there a way in iOS that my application can say remind me at this time and my app should be reminded at that particular mentioned time.

Comment: No, I think there is no reliable way by which you can sync at specified times. The background operations (events) for an app are limited on iOS. However, iOS 7 onwards, the underlying OS __may__ silently wake up your app to perform some operation (sync) based on the user's regular usage of app.

Comment: Ya Ashok i need this behaviour on iOS7 only. If you have any link or some info please help.

Comment: @Ashok looks like there is a way in iOS7 http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch/ but problem is i am not getting event if i set time interval is 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes, i meant this. There was a video in Apple's WWDC conference about this. Let's discuss your concerns (specific questions) in my answer. Nevertheless, a good question +1.

Answer (score 3):

**Background Fetch** is an opportunity provided by OS (**iOS 7 onwards**) to the apps who requested to perform an operation when in background, however leaving on OS to decide the timing. The OS will silently awake your app (actually a handler method) in background after learning about the user's usage of an app.

**Feature usage:** As of now, this feature has been introduced in iOS7 to enhance usability of social media, newspaper etc daily/frequent/heavy content refreshing apps.

**Note**- its *just a request that is not guaranteed* to be fulfilled but an attempt of underlying OS to better user experience)

From coding/implementation perspective, there are primarily 2-3 key steps -

A)
Turn ON `Background Modes` for `Background Fetch` attribute (*Select App Target > Capabilities > Background Modes > Background Fetch*)
[image]

B) Implement this app delegate method -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

C) Define your fetch interval, typically when app launches - i.e appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

---

Since it's an event fired by OS automatically, how to test this behavior during development -

Well, you can simulate/test the background fetch behavior in your app through *XCode 5+* using menu *Debug > Simulate Background Fetch*

[image]

Here is the [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch/) to the tutorial with sample project.

Also, you can checkout session 204 from Apple's WWDC 2013 videos - [What's New with Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

**EDIT -**

As of today (iOS 7.0.3), in lack of proper official documentation, the practical usage tells that -

1. The enforced minimumBackgroundFetchInterval is between than 5 to 15 minutes (anything less than it is not honored).
2. The background fetch doesn't happen when device is locked.
3. The background fetch is triggered immediately after the device is unlocked by user.

However, in upcoming versions, I feel this feature would be enhanced and giving more power to developers/users.

Comment: Having done a little reading around this, using `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` as the minimum fetch interval will mean that the system will decide when to fetch. Apparently, if you pass an `NSTimeInterval` to `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` it allows you to override this and set your own fetch interval. [Article here.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-mutlitasking-enhancements/)

Comment: Me too taught it would do the same.If i pass 10 seconds it is not at all giving any event after 10 seconds. I tried waiting till 20 minutes no event !! :( As mentioned in the Article if simulate the fetch event from xcode then i receive the event..this is the problem i am facing.

Comment: @YugandharPathi Have you tried running this on a device? Perhaps the background fetch operation can only be simulated in the Simulator? (This is entirely speculation)

Also, did you have a look at that article I posted in my last comment? Was it of any help?

Comment: The background fetch handler does get fired on device but after few minutes (_in range 5 to 15 minutes_) as soon as you __unlock__ (wake up) the device. So far I have noticed that it's not called when device is locked. "Unlock" device by user is probably a __trigger__ point. I think "10" seconds is too less a time. In such case, perhaps system has it's own minimum time interval (in minutes) and override your/custom minimum interval.

Comment: @Ashok: I gave 10 seconds for testing purpose.Me too feel the same like event is not getting fired when device is locked. I don't know what is the true use of this feature. My app needs to sync at every day night 1AM.At this time device might be locked for sure.

Comment: @YugandharPathi - As I told, iOS doesn't provide any reliable mechanism which guarantees this. In future iOS releases, _Background Fetch_ may be extended in this direction. But, also note that the user may turn off device / internet / background refresh etc. You may like to consider using Apple push notification Service (APNS) if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSLocalNotification`. See an example (taken from [here](http://www.cocoaosx.com/2012/02/17/usando-local-notifications-en-ios/)):

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// Activate in 5 segundos
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];

// message to show 
notification.alertBody = self.nameTextField.text;

// default sound
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

// button title
notification.alertAction = @"Ahora te lo cuento";
notification.hasAction = YES;

// activa la notificación
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

The point is that the behaviour depends on the application state when the local notification fires. If the app is running on the foreground, you can handle the notification silently. But if the app is not running, or it's in the background, user interaction is required.

Comment: The way I read the question Yugandhar is asking for a way to initiate a background process at a certain time, not simply display a notification at a certain time. They are asking if there is a way for the application to subscribe to an internal scheduler which will fire a particular method at a certain time. As far as I'm aware, this doesn't exist in iOS.

Comment: @GaryEmery If what you describe is what he is looking for, I agree, that doesn't exists in iOS. In that case, I'll wait for OP clarification, and delete my answer if it is not helpful to him.

Comment: @GaryEmery I am from Symbian background. In Symbian, application can register private event with calendar(events) application (This will not be shown in UI). When that particular time is reached application will be given the event(This will again not be shown on the UI).Is there any thing similar to this in iOS.         neutrino: Please don't delete this answer it may be helpful for some one else.

Comment: @YugandharPathi Ok, I'll leave the answer here. Regarding your last question, the answer is no. In iOS, the equivalent to what you describe is what I say in my answer. The only exceptions are described in this Apple's document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Comment: @GaryEmery Looks like there is way in iOS7   http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch/ but problem is i am not gettting the event if i set time as 10 seconds

Comment: @YugandharPathi Yes, but read carefully the Apple docs about that option, as I said in my last comment.

Comment: @YugandharPathi did you pass the 10 seconds through as an `NSTimeInterval`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a combination of Apple Push Notifications and Background Transfer Service.  If you watch the WWDC 2013 Video to which Ashok referred, in the video they alluded to having silent push notifications wake the app which will then let you configure a background transfer.

You could register your app to have Push Notifications, have your server send a request for notification to Apple, then when the push notification is received, your app wakes from background, you configure your download/upload using NSURLSession, then start the session.  When the data transfer is complete, run whatever code you require to sync your app, then notify the OS that your background transfer is complete so that it can put your app back to sleep.

Note that the timing is still not really under your control, but this is about as close as I can see to creating a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully implemented @Steve's solution - e.g. implementing Apple Push Notifications without the Background Transfer Service. My app relies on creating EKCalendar events which then will trigger the creation of a push notification for the specific start/end date/time. The app uses the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` function in the app delegate which handles the receipt of the remote notification and then subsequently executes some code to perform the app's necessary functionality based on the event. Note: the remote notification message must include the `content-available` set to 1. The only downside is the reliance upon the timely delivery of the remote notifications, which so-far during my testing has proven to be about 95+% effective/accurate to within 2-30+ seconds, but I've also seen cases where the notifications are never received or > 1-5+ minutes delayed. This is infrequent and for my purposes acceptable for my app's functionality.